# HTTP Smart Proxy in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

is there any way to implement the Smart Proxy Pattern under Spring Cloud Streams? Having a HTTP Source that get a request connected to other micro services (or processors) and finally return the response through the same connection that was made in the request?

Using Spring Cloud Data Flow maybe it is difficult but by using the Spring Cloud Stream should be possible isn't it?

Thanks.